# Is it customary to call a zig-zag of quasi-isomorphisms a weak homotopy equivalence?

Tags: terminology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Is it customary to call a zig-zag of quasi-isomorphisms *a weak homotopy equivalence*?
$$ A_0 \leftarrow A_1 \rightarrow \dotsb \leftarrow A_{k-1}\rightarrow A_k $$

Could someone, please, elaborate on the notions of a homotopy equivalence, weak homotopy equivalence and quasi-isomorphism in the context of model categories?

Comment: "Weak homotopy equivalence" is a term used in the context of topological spaces (or related objects). "Quasi-isomorphism" is a term used in the context of chain complexes. What context are you asking about?

Comment: @ZhenLin +1, but some people consider chain complexes sufficiently "related" to topological spaces to justify transferring terminology from one context to the other (e.g., homotopic maps, mapping cones).

Comment: @ZhenLin, I agree that the question is vague, but I got a good answer below! My context: I have some structure on homology, let's call it an O-algebra, pick its chain model A, which is a dO-algebra, and associate to it some infinity-structure on its bar complex BA. It turns out that if the chain models are weakly homotopy equivalent as dO-algebras, then the infinity structures on the bar complexes are quasi-isomorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it customary to call a zig-zag of quasi-isomorphisms a weak homotopy equivalence?  A0←A1→⋯←Ak−1→Ak

No, a weak homotopy equivalence is a single map.
You can refer to the above chain as a zigzag of weak homotopy equivalences.
Two objects A and B are weakly homotopy equivalent if they can be connected by a zigzag of weak homotopy equivalences.

> Could someone, please, elaborate on the notions of a homotopy equivalence, weak homotopy equivalence and quasi-isomorphism in an abstract setting and discuss the (sometimes different?) usage of these terms in the literature?

The term “quasi-isomorphism” always refers to a particular
type of weak equivalence between chain complexes:
a chain map that induces isomorphisms on all homology groups.

Weak homotopy equivalences (or simply weak equivalences)
make sense in any model category, or, more generally, relative category.
“Weak” means that for a weak equivalence A→B there need not exist a morphism B→A.

Homotopy equivalences are defined as maps A→B for which there is a map
B→A such that both compositions A→B→A and B→A→B are homotopic to identity maps.
Here “homotopic maps” can be interpreted in a variety of contexts,
including, at the very least,
relative categories, model categories, differential graded categories, simplicial categories,
categories enriched over monoidal model categories,
and many other notions.

Comment: Thank you very much! The crucial lesson for me is that I can still call $A_0$ and $A_k$ weakly homotopy equivalent, but the zig-zig (which is in fact an isomorphism in the derived category, right?) should not be called a weak homotopy equivalence (except for the case that $k=1$, when the direction of the arrow has to be specified additionally).

Comment: @Pavel: Yes, zigzag of weak equivalences induces an isomorphism in the homotopy category.  Conversely, any isomorpishm in the homotopy category arises in such a manner.  This is valid in full generality for model categories and relative categories.  (For chain complexes, the homotopy category for quasi-isomorphisms is known as the derived category, whereas the homotopy category for chain homotopy equivalences is known simply as the homotopy category, the two should not be confused.)